# Alignment in \addchap left and right at the same time

Tags: spacing, chapters, koma-script

I'm using `scrbook` and want to accomplish the following: The chapter (unnumbered) shall be devided in two parts
- one ragged left and bold 
and
- one ragged right and normal font

Now I get a strange space for `\addchap` on the right border (but not for `\addsec`). Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

My minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \addchap{Text for left side \hfill \normalfont Text for right side}
    \blindtext
    \addsec{Text for left side \hfill \normalfont Text for right side}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will be fixed in the next KOMA-Script version. However, AFAIK it will take a while until version 3.20 will be published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a brute force fix, but I don't know why the problem arises.  The definition of `\hfill` is `\hskip 0pt plus 1fill minus 0pt`, so I decided to amplify what it does by defining `\Hfill`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand\Hfill{\hskip 0pt plus 1000fill minus 0pt}
\begin{document}
    \addchap{Text for left side \Hfill \normalfont Text for right side}
    \blindtext
    \addsec{Text for left side \hfill \normalfont Text for right side}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Banarama You are welcome. Best wishes!